# Installing gcc on OSX 10.10

Tags: c, macos, gcc

Gcc was running in my system until I started using the eclipse IDE (for school reasons) and encountered a problem where it would or would not compile my code randomly. Long story short now I don't have gcc installed on my mac (gcc -v returns "gcc : command not found"). I've tried installing command line tools, Xcode,  command line tools and Xcode with no result. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) Do you still have Xcode installed, and if so, what version? (2) Do you want gcc or would clang also be fine? (Maybe you still need gcc for school though.)

Comment: usually gcc in OSX is linked to Clang. Do you remember if that was the case? Or did you install it via macports or homebrew separately?

Comment: I still have Xcode installed v6.1.1 I need gcc.

Comment: I don't know if gcc was linked to Clang the first time I installed it it was through the command line tools. I haven't tried macports nor homebrew so far. I'll do some research whether they are suitable for me and try them out.